# Do I need disallow other websites directory in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a hosting which has several websites in `www` folder. I set up a WordPress website in root directory for main domain.

Do I need disallow other websites directory in *robots.txt*? I think these directories are not relate to the main domain. But is this will totally disallow other website?

Comment: Adding [disallow](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) tells robots to ignore the specified disallowed directories. However if there are other links to them (such as external links), they may get crawled anyway. If you want to "totally" disallow them from appearing in search engines, then prevent them from being crawled (e.g., password protect them).

Answer (score 1):

You could use *robots.txt* to block the directories but there is an easier way by using canonical pages on your websites.

This will ensure sites that are hosted within containers within 1 hosting account for example:

- `/public_html/` = `domain1.com`
- `/public_html/domain2.com` = `domain2.com` would only be indexed on the domain that the [canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) is setup on.